# qt5 git: 5.9 or 5.9.0

Tags: git, qt5

I'm going to clone the qt5 [repository](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git) in order to cross-compile. I'm not sure to understand the difference between the branches `5.9` and `5.9.0`.

And how could exists a tag `v5.9.1` if the latest branch is `5.9.0`? As far as I know, a tag points to a particular state of a branch at a given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branching scheme is explained [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Branch_Guidelines).

At the time of this answer, the situation is as follows:

`5.9` is the branch for all the 5.9 releases (5.9.0, 5.9.1, and so on). `5.9.0` is instead the release branch for version 5.9.0; it was branched off 5.9 and the 5.9.0 release happened off it. The actual released commit is tagged (`v5.9.0`, notice the leading `v`). After the release `5.9.0` was merged back into `5.9` and the branch closed for public submission.

I'm not sure why a 5.9.1 branch doesn't exist, it was probably accidentally deleted. Anyhow, release branches aren't *that* important to keep (as they're merged back, and noone can modify them).

So, if you want to use 5.9 "tip" use the `5.9` branch. If you want to checkout a specific release checkout the release tag.